# Check Array A for Array B Permutations

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

**OBJECTIVE**

Given Array A and Array B, see if Array B's values are within Array A (disregard sequence/order). Essentially, we're checking to see if all of the letters contained in one array are, in some form, contained in another array.

**EXAMPLE #1**

```
mutation(['hello', 'hey']);
```

**OUTPUT #1**

```
false //no 'y' in 'hello'
```

---

**EXAMPLE #2**

```
mutation(['Alien', 'line']))
```

**OUTPUT #2**

```
true //'l','i','n','e' is present in 'Alien'
```

---

---

**MY PSEUDO-CODE/ATTEMPT**

```
function mutation(arr) {
  //split into two arrays with individual letters (for comparison purposes)
  var arr0 = arr[0].split('');
  var arr1 = arr[1].split('');

  //if the letters in arr[1] exceed arr[0], there is no match (no matter what) 
  if (arr1 > arr0) {
    return false;
  } 
  //if arr0 > arr1 check each letter or arr1[i] against arr0[j]. 
  else if (arr0 > arr1) { 
    for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      //compare arr1[i] to all arr0[j] values
      //if all of arr1 is present in arr0, return true
      return true;
    }

  } else {
    //If one of arr1's letters is not present in arr0, return false
    return false; 
  }
}

mutation(['hello', 'hey']);
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. I know that this can be solved with "recursion", but am unsure on how to properly execute this. I think I am on the right path but any guidance would be appreciated.
2. How can I use a FOR loop to iterate through two different variable (e.g arr0[i] and arr1[j])?

Comment: You mean you have exactly two strings and want to check if one contains all the letters of the other? Can there ever be more than two?

Comment: @SpiderPig - there can never be more than two arguments.

Comment: @DavidThomas Indeed they start off as strings, but I thought breaking them down into individual arrays would enable me to loop through each letter of each array for 'checking' purposes. Perhaps this is not the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pseudo code would give false positives when for example looking for `"aaa"` in `"bad"`. You need to remove characters from the first string when they match characters in the second string, so that they are not reused for duplicate characters in the second string.

Loop through the characters in the second string and look for them in the first string. If it's found remove it from the first string, otherwise return false. If all characters are found, return true:

```
function mutation(str1, str2){
  for (var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    var index = str1.indexOf(str2.charAt(i));
    if (index == -1) return false;
    str1 = str1.substr(0, index) + str1.substr(index + 1);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain "str1 = str1.substr(0, index) + str1.substr(index + 1)" and its purpose?

From my understanding, your code is saying the following:

Comment: @kidlogic: That will remove the character at position `index`. It takes the part of the string before that character plus the part of the string after that character.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The 'brute force' way of solving this is to use 2 nested for loops to iterate through the arrays. However, this will result in O(n^2) runtime complexity.

To solve this in O(n) runtime complexity, store all array A's values in a hash then check if array B's values are in the hash. Note that this solution still has 2 for loops, the difference is they are not nested which results in O(n) runtime complexity.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5s0rbedr/1/)

```
var mutation = function(arr) {    
    var areBInA = true;

    // Convert from string to array
    var a = arr[0].split('');
    var b = arr[1].split('');
    console.log('a b %o %o', a, b);

    // Create hash for array A
    var aHash = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        aHash[a[i]] = 1;
    }
    console.log('aHash %o', aHash);

    // Check if array B values are in hash A
    for(var i = 0; i < b.length; ++i) {
        if(aHash[b[i]] !== 1) {
            console.log('fail at %o', b[i]);
            areBInA = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return areBInA;
};

console.log('hello hey %o', mutation(['hello', 'hey']));
console.log('Alien line %o', mutation(['Alien', 'line']));
```